# Moving Fusion VMs to ESXi

Tags: vmware, virtualization

I am in the process of moving several VMs created in VMWare Fusion 5 into ESXi 5.1, which I just installed on a Mac Mini Server. I am able to connect just fine via the Windows application installed on another VM. I have created two OVF files, one for Server 2003 and another for Server 2012. Both files were created without incident. I am able to upload them to the ESXi server seemingly without issue as well.

However, when I start either of the VMs, I get the following error(s):

Console:

[image]

And in the GUI:

[image]

I'm unsure how to proceed, as I have followed the steps outlined to create an OVF file and upload it to the ESX. Both of these VMs work fine through Fusion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just guessing, but it looks like there's a problem with the virtual hard disk; maybe it's not connected as expected.  I'd check there first.

Comment: @zigg, I've redone the VM conversion several times. Each time, I reload it, and get the same error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After arduous research and trial and error, I've finally been able to solve this issue. First of all, if you're migrating Fusion VMs to ESXi, I recommend not using the OVF tool. At least for me, it never worked properly. Instead, I used the `vmware-vdiskmanager` tool, which is built into Fusion. The instructions for this migration are listed below:

> 1. Open Terminal.
> 2. Run the following command, inserting the correct VMWare Fusion vmdk file source and new vmdk destination:
>
>    > `/Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmware-vdiskmanager -r /PATH/TO/vmware_fusion.vmwarevm/vmware_fusion.vmdk -t 4 /PATH/TO/esxi.vmdk`
> 3. The conversion process, once complete, will create two files: `filename.vmdk`, and `filename-flat.vmdk`.
> 4. Launch the vSphere client through your web browser to your ESXi server.
> 5. Once logged in, go to `File | New | Virtual Machine`.
> 6. In the Configuration window, select `Custom`.
> 7. In the Storage window, select the datastore location to store the new VM.
> 8. In the Virtual Machine Version window, use the default option of `Virtual Machine Version: 8.`
> 9. Select the desired settings for `Guest OS, CPUs, Memory, Network`, and `SCSI Controller`.
> 10. In the Select a Disk window, choose the `Do Not Create Disk` option.
> 11. Click the `Finish` button.
> 12. In the ESXi server settings, select the Configuration tab then click on `Storage`.
> 13. In Storage, select your datastore and right-click to select `Browse Datastore`.
> 14. Select the folder name that corresponds to the new VM.
> 15. Select the `Upload` button.
> 16. Upload the `filename.vmdk` and `filename-flat.vmdk` files from Step 3.
> 17. Once complete, you will only see the `filename.vmdk` file in the datastore.
> 18. Select the VM and `Edit virtual machine settings` under the `Get Started` tab.
> 19. Click the `Add` button in the `Virtual Machine Properties` window.
> 20. For Device Type, select `Hard Disk`, and choose `Use an existing virtual disk`.
> 21. Locate the datastore and select the existing disk.
> 22. In the `Advanced Options`, leave the default settings.
> 23. Select `Finish` and `OK` to close the Virtual Machine Properties.
> 24. At this point, you should be able to boot to the newly migrated VM.

Guidance for this came from MacTech's June 2013 issue, reproduced at the author's blog [here](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/04/16/migrating-os-x-vms-files-without-vmware-standalone-converter/). Many kudos to Rich Trouton for this article.

**Some updates for vSphere Client 6.7**

- Step 5: Go to `Actions | New Virtual Machine`.
- Steps 6 - 9: Configure as desired.
- Step 10: In the `Customize hardware` dialog, remove the `New hard disk`.
- Step 12 - 13: Select storage, then `Files`.
- Step 18: Select the VM and then `Actions | Edit Settings...`.
- Step 19: Click the `Add New Device` button.
- Step 20: Select `Existing Hard Disk`.
- Step 22: Ignore.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the VMWare converter to move the virtual machines from one host to another. This will do all the heavy lifting for you. It's free.

http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/

This is your best option as the converter does all the vm configurations and settings for you. This is also suggested in the [KB Article (1000936)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1000936) from VMWare.

You have to do this on a windows machine. Inside a VM on the same fusion host works just fine.

Comment: I've been unable to find a Mac version of the VMWare Converter, so I'll give this a whirl once I stand up a non-production Windows machine for the operation.

Comment: Ok, I just run it inside a win7 vm. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: The conversion process worked, or did so apparently. However, when I upload the files via the ESXi interface, they load to the file system, but they give me the same error as above. I'm missing something somewhere.

Comment: You should have been able to convert and install the vm directly to the esxi server without needing to copy any files.

Comment: If it is a VM that originated from a product other than Fusion, the process works fine. It's the conversion of Fusion VMs that is giving me the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There has been an update to OVFTOOL around since March 2015 (Now V4.1.0.). With this OSX version I have much fewer trouble to get OVFTool to work. Even a OSX VM transfer from Fusion to ESXi is now just a one line like:

```
/Applications/VMware\ OVF\ Tool/ovftool --compress=9 ./OS_X_10.vmx vi://root@ESX6i
```

Finally it is working like expected, when the old versions just copied parts or I had to try 10 times to get the desired results with some crude workarounds.
So please give it another try! ;)

Comment: excellent! I'll have to give that a try.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working to do what you wanted @Dave? As although your answer above does work, I'm also trying alternative solutions

Comment: Yes, I did. I'd be interested in your alternate solutions as well.