# Shrinking VMWare flat esxi images

Tags: virtualization, vmware, disk-space, virtual-memory

I've been following [Moving Fusion VMs to ESXi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99433/moving-fusion-vms-to-esxi) on moving VMWare Fusion images into VSphere Cloud/ESXi, and am unsure of something that comes out of this.

When running the following command:

```
/Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmware-vdiskmanager
> -r /path/to/vmware_fusion.vmwarevm/vmware_fusion.vmdk -t 4 /path/to/esxi.vmdk
```

It generates two files, `filename.vmdk`, and `filename-flat.vmdk`.

My original `vmware_fusion.vmdk` is a single growable virtual disk which starts at 40GB. After running the above command, the `filename-flat.vmdk` is over 120GB!

Is there anyway I can shrink or convert that back down to 40GB and have it act as a growable virtual disk within VSphere Cloud?